# rbenv: version `2.0.0' is not installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to install the Gemfile contents using `Bundle install` but getting the error

```
rbenv: version `2.0.0' is not installed
```

The version of `ruby` installed in my system is:

```
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [i686-linux]
```

and rbenv

```
 2.1.2 (set by /home/jay/.rbenv/version)
 2.1.3
```

The `Gemfile` requires `ruby "2.0.0"`. Can any one tell how to install the required version without affecting the existing ones.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can find a lot of information here: [rbenv on github](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)

To list all available installation candidates:

```
rbenv install -l
```

To install a ruby version you need (for example):

```
rbenv install 2.0.0-p643
```

So that you will only use this ruby version in this specific folder and not affect anything else you can do:

```
rbenv local 2.0.0-p643
```

This will generate a .ruby-version file in that directory which will force rbenv to use this ruby version here.

Comment: If your desired version does not show up upon `rbenv install -l`, reinstall ruby-build (on mac: `brew reinstall --HEAD ruby-build`). The do `rbenv install -l`.

Comment: @septerr The lower-case `-l` switch only shows latest stable versions. The upper-case `-L` shows all available versions. So, before doing what you suggest, I suggest anyone first try the upper-case `-L`. I found the version I was looking for when I did, and it didn't show up when I used `-l`.

Answer (score 5):

Just run:

```
rbenv install 2.0.0-p643
```

Which is the lastest 2.0.0 version.

If that version is not available on your system, run `ruby-build --definitions` to pick the lastest known 2.0.0 version on your system.

Comment: This does not fix the listed error, as `2.0.0-p643` is unequal to `2.0.0`.

Answer (score 3):

You must change the ruby's version in `.ruby-version` file and in `Gemfile`

Answer (score 2):

For me, I just ran 
`gem install bundler` 
and then run 
`bundle install`
worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a `build failed` error when trying to run `rbenv install 2.0.0-p643` and after waiting for a few minutes; you might also see the `last 10 lines` of a log file as an output.

This can give you the hint of what would have happened for the build failure. It might miss some required library/dependency needed to be installed.

For ex. I got the following error for build failure-

```
ERROR: Ruby install aborted due to missing extensions
Try running `apt-get install -y libreadline-dev` to fetch missing dependencies.
```